# Linq Expression tree

Tags: linq, expression-trees

I want to generate expression tree like

```
StatusRAG.where(x=> (overallRAG.Contains(x.OverallRAG) == overallRAGinclusive) || (costRAG.Contains(x.CostRAG) == costRAGinclusive))
```

Here is my data:

```
var overallRAG  = new  List<string>(){"Red", "Green"}
var costRAG  = new  List<string>(){"Red", "Amber"}
bool overallRAGinclusive = true
bool costRAGinclusive = false
class StatusRAG
{
    public OverallRAG {get; set;}
    public CostRAG {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I want to apply dynamic filter. From UI user can select overallRAG value(s) (Red, Green, Amber) and may want to include or exclude those data.User may apply filter on both RAGs or only 1.

Answer (score 0):

Linq expression wrong. I think you need not equal of costrag.

```
StatusRAG.where (x=> overallRAG.Contains(x.OverallRAG) || !costRAG.Contains(x.CostRAG))
```

Comment: No, I am simply looking to generate dynamic expression like:
StatusRAG.where (x=> overallRAG.Contains(x.OverallRAG))